# How to change a Jackrabbit persistence manager on the fly?

Tags: derby, jackrabbit, file-storage

I used internal persistence manager based on derby DB, and filesystem repository.

Now it around 1.5 million files and 3 TB in repo, and around 6 million records in derby DB.

I think is too much for that DB, because I have extremely slowing down on performance last time.

so I want to change persistence manager to something like MySQL or Oracle.

What is the best way to export data from a Apache Jackrabbit derby DB and import to MySQL?

How can I do this in the easiest and fastest way?

Comment: Do you want it changed on the fly - at runtime - or just to keep your data when changing the persistence manager?

Comment: no, I don't need 24x7 runtime, I mean keep data without exporting it to some another place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to migrate to a version of Jackrabbit or a new [persistence manager](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ) is described at the [Backup and Migration](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/BackupAndMigration) page.

In my experience, MySQL or Oracle are not actually faster, is Derby is embedded (in-process). MySQL and Oracle are remote, so for each request there is a network roundtrip.

Instead, what you could do is use a higher [bundle cache size](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.5/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/persistence/bundle/BundleDbPersistenceManager.html) and/or a higher database cache size.

Comment: possible you right, I have check performance on much smaller db and it was same as derby. but I not sure what in large db result will be same. I want to try. because profiling tool (dynatrace) shows that inset to db took around seven seconds. it too much, but on small db it took only few milliseconds, I believe than on external db with millions of records it will be faster, also with network latency. I think that indexes don't help much on insert operations.

Comment: The problem with large repositories is the randomly distributed node id, see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-2857